# QSS QTabBar text-align does not work

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget, qtstylesheets, qtabbar

I try (`font-weigth:` works, but `text-align:` does not work):

```
QTabBar::tab:text{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
}
```

I try, but it was also not working:

```
QTabBar::tab {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
}
```

My *QTabWidget*:

```
<item>
 <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
  <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
   <attribute name="title">
    <string>Tab 1</string>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
   <attribute name="title">
    <string>Tab 2</string>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
 </widget>
</item>
```

I also have not found any *"property"* (`<property name="...">`) that aligns the text.

how to use the *"QSS"* to align the text of the tabs (`QTabBar/QTabWidget`) ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is supported in the current version of Qt (5.4). You can try using a paint event with `QPainter` to draw the text onto the tab in the alignment you want.

You could use specific padding and `Qt::AlignLeft` to get this outcome potentially.

See this post on the Qt forum for more info - https://forum.qt.io/topic/35405/qss-qtabbar-text-align-does-not-work

Comment: Note https://forum.qt.io/topic/35405/qss-qtabbar-text-align-does-not-work this question is mine :) (I'm the Brcotainer user)

Comment: Ahhh okay, makes sense - seemed like a very specific question related to this one. Is there a Qt bug report page for this, as I would probably say this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try `setElideMode(Qt::ElideRight);`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can pad the title with spaces at the end, use `setElideMode(Qt::ElideRight)` and use a custom QTabBar with reimplemented `sizeHint()` to avoid stretched tabs:

```
QSize TabBar::tabSizeHint(int index) const {
    QSize size = QTabBar::tabSizeHint(index);
    size.setWidth(250);
    return size;
}
```